# Design pattern to model content

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, mapping

I am trying to find the best way to solve this situation :

A product `P` can be bought from `X` different `Shops`, each shop has a different price for the product `P`.

Below are my models, what would be the best way to store and display the prices of a give Product from all shops. .

```
@Entity
public class Product extends Model {
    @Required
    public String name;
    @Required
    double price;
}


@Entity
public class Shop extends Model {
@Required
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in this model you have many-to-many relation between `products` and `shops`.
Right now in your Model it's reflected only from `Shops` side, but you also can create a link ( `List` ) of shops where this product is represented.